# Migration SQL Source with Track Changes

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a D8 migration from a SQL source to nodes which is working perfectly apart from `track_changes` is not working, in my YAML I simply have:

```
source:
  plugin: job
  constants:
    slash: /
  track_changes: true
```

I discovered [track_changes does not work when the map is joinable](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2787185) and applied the patch, but every time I run the migration I get:

`[notice] Processed 0 items (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'job'`

Do I need to add anything specific to the source plugin? For now I'm getting round this by updating the whole migration each time, but I would prefer not to. If necessary I will have to use the `high_water_property` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like you did and i solve it by changing my:

```
track_changes: true
```

on

```
  high_water_property:
    name: changed
    alias: n
```

But the problem with this way that you need to:

1. Manually **delete**, NOT update your database destination fields.
2. Import old data.(Before check your source plugin, it must have **changed** field!)
3. Update your database with new data.

(and only than *high_water_property* will work)

> [About this two Source Plugins](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21source%21SourcePluginBase.php/class/SourcePluginBase/8.4.x)
>
> [Declaring highwater property in Migrate](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158627/declaring-highwater-property-in-migrate)
>
> [About track_changes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-source-plugins/overview-of-migrate-source-plugins)